# Democracy pallet vs referenda pallet for calling a "private" function

Tags: democracy, pallet-democracy, referenda

I'm trying to figure out the best route to take to accomplish calling specific functions that are not publicly available for accounts to freely call

I have a few functions I want only to be called by users voting and/or delegating voting.

Which pallet or pallets should be implemented to accomplish this?